# flycheck include path from ede

Tags: flycheck, c, cedet

I have a setup where I use EDE from CEDET for C projects development (among other things) and the real good flycheck on-the-fly syntax checking.

I have defined ede-cpp-root-project in my .emacs file for several projects where I have set project include-path variable to include the whole set of my project includes for each project. This works splendidly; auto-complete works and the all the includes are found by the semantic package for every project.

**Now the question is how to set up this same include path for flycheck without heavy duplication?**

Edit: I'm using gcc with flycheck, although I guess it doesn't make too much difference compare to clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer at: https://ogbe.net/emacsconfig.html

Copy-paste from the page:

> Projects
>
> In some projects, flycheck needs some information about the projects include path. Since we want to use EDE for C and C++ projects anyways, we can grab the include path from there.

```
(require 'ede)
(global-ede-mode t)
(require 'flycheck-cedet)

(defun dennis-flycheck-get-ede-includes ()
 (interactive)
 "Check if the current file is part of an EDE project.
  If yes, set up `flycheck-clang-include-path'"
 (make-variable-buffer-local 'flycheck-clang-include-path)
 (let* ((rel-includes
          (flycheck-cedet-get-cpp-includes "" (buffer-file-name)))
         (dirname (when rel-includes
                    (ede-cpp-root-project-root default-directory))))
    (when rel-includes
      (when (string-match "\\(.*\\)/$" dirname)
        (setq dirname (substring dirname (match-beginning 1) (match-end 1))))
      (setq incl-paths
            (mapcar '(lambda (arg) (concat dirname arg))
                    rel-includes))
      (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
            (append flycheck-clang-include-path incl-paths)))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'dennis-flycheck-get-ede-includes)
```

> We can now list our current EDE projects. This is not being exported.

This one is referencing flycheck-cedet. It can be found here:
https://github.com/dholm/flycheck-cedet

Answer (score 0):

Other option is not to use EDE but to use projectile! See https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile . Add .projectile file to the project root to make it a projectile project and this to .emacs:

```
(require 'projectile)
(defun setup-flycheck-gcc-includes ()
  "Set gcc includes for flycheck using projectile."
  (let ((root (ignore-errors (projectile-project-root))))
    (when root
      (setq-local flycheck-gcc-include-path
                  (mapcar (lambda (dir-x)
                            (concat root dir-x)) (projectile-current-project-dirs))))))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'setup-flycheck-gcc-includes)
```

I know that this adds every subdir that the projectile considers as project directory as a possible include directory. One might want to filter the list with some magic regex or something if one has better knowledge on which dirs are include dirs.